# QtSQL: "prepared statement "qpsqlpstmt_1" does not exist" on clear() of model

Tags: qt, postgresql

I am getting the following error message printed in the console:

```
Unable to free statement: ERROR:  prepared statement "qpsqlpstmt_1" does not exist
```

It is printed when the the following function is called in the application (or when the object is deleted (if `clear()` is not called before delete):

```
sqlQueryModel->clear();
```

sqlQueryModel object is of type `QSqlQueryModel` and is used throughout a derived class to communicated with a PostgreSQL database. It also serves as a model for `QCompleter`. I have never declared or used the name `"qpsqlpstmt_1"`.

Could someone help me interpret the error message please, and explain what might be causing it? Is this indicative of a problem in my code or a Qt bug? (likely the former :))

On reviewing the PostgreSQL log file on the server, the exact same statement appears plus an additional line:

```
STATEMENT: DEALLOCATE pqsqlpstmt_1
```

Comment: Qt version? If you suspect a Qt bug, surely you should specify your Qt version...

Comment: It looks like `qpsqlpstmt_1` is used internally by Qt.

Comment: Is it worth doing further research into the issue and possibly submit a bug report, considering the answer below?

Comment: I'd recommend trying to boil the problem code down to a minimal compilable test case that demonstrates the issue, *then* consider filing a bug report.

Comment: You should also search the PostgreSQL logs to see whether Qt tried to use the name `pqsqlpstmt_1` in some line prior to the error, perhaps a statement with a syntax error that failed to PREPARE?

Comment: No other errors in the log. I'll try to boil it down to minimal code  and see what happens. Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a considerable amount of time, I realized that I was simply closing the connection to the database before calling clear... not a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

See these Qt issue tracker entries:

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8860
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16007
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15979

... all of which mention your prepared statement name and relate to deletion.